# Does threadpool get shared between application domains?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, clr

Consider a process which is creating multiple application domains. Do these Application domains share same thread pool? If yes, how is it coordinated between multiple application domains?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ThreadPool is shared across all appdomains - since that means threads might end up switching between appdomains (potentially often!) there's been perf work around that:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericeil/clr-4-0-threadpool-improvements-part-1)

> [...] In fact, we violate this “rule”
> already: since .NET 3.5, the CLR
> thread pool has maintained separate
> FIFO queues for each AppDomain in the
> process, and an additional independent
> FIFO queue for “native” work items
> such as those queued by a host
> (ASP.net being the prime user of this
> feature).  We round-robin between
> these work queues, allowing each to
> execute work for some time before
> moving on to the next.[...]

BTW, note that strictly speaking the ThreadPool isn't shared across the entire process anymore, since the v4 CLR allows loading side-by-side with V2, and each will have its own threadpool.

Answer (score 5):

The threadpool is shared between all appdomains, as each threadpool thread is context-agnostic and the whole threadpool runtime profile is highly dependent on the hardware you are running on (# of procs, hyperthreading and such)

> There is one thread pool per process.
>   The thread pool has a default size of
>   25 threads per available processor.
>   The number of threads in the thread
>   pool can be changed using the
>   SetMaxThreads method. Each thread uses
>   the default stack size and runs at the
>   default priority.

Source : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx

If I remember correctly, the CLR handles the threadpool threads internally and cleans the thread context before serving another work request.

Comment: This is the link to the latest documentation for .NET 4. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx. There is 250 worker threads per available processor.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but I think thread pool is 
once per process, not once per AppDomain. Try look at this article on [thread & appdomain](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/IPC.aspx) :