# Threadpool instance on same/different CLR

Tags: .net, threadpool

I have 3 .net process that run on the machine ( no connection between each of the processes ) 
All of the processes compiled using the same .net version ( lets say .net 4.0 )

1. Does all of the processes using the same threadPool ? 
   Does threadPool instance is per CLR that run on the machine ? or each of process hold his own threadPool ?
2. In case one of the process is compiled using .net 2.0 => is there will be now more threadPool instance ( that will increase the overhead because more threadPool instance will formation of new thread that will appear in this new threadPool ) ?

Comment: This would probably answer your question as well
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447384/does-threadpool-get-shared-between-application-domains

Comment: thanls, but what about different CLR's ?

Comment: Different version of CLR uses different thread pool! Does that you wanted to ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ThreadPool is just a managed wrapper around a producer/consumer queue - that will be per AppDomain. It will not be shared between processes. There is usually one AppDomain per process, but even if you create multiple AppDomain instances in a single process, the ThreadPools will be separate. Note, however, that managed and unmanaged threads are not the same thing: how the managed threads get serviced by the unmanaged threads of the process is an implementation detail.